# Laravel 8: min & max validation depends on the previous selected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

In the application, there is a configurations called "Products" where some of the fields are: minimum amount and maximum amount.

In the registration module, fields are: products & amount. The user will choose what kind of product they will avail/buy. The amount should not be less than the minimum amount but not greater than the maximum amount.

**For example**

In my Products I have the ff:

```
Product 1: 

Minimum Amount: $5,000
Maximum Amount: $50,000

Product 2:
Minimum Amount: $500
Maximum Amount: $4,500
```

User choose Product 1,

```
Amount: 500
```

Once the user clicked the saved, there will be an error, "amount should not be less than to xxx" or "amount should not be greater than to xxx"

Question: Is it possible to make the min & max of laravel validation depends on the selected of the products?

**UPDATED POST**

**Laravel validation**

```
$this->validate([
            'amount'        => 'required|min:xx|max:xx',
                    ]);
```

**Products table**

```
id
name
minimum_amount
maximum_amount
```

Comment: Not sure how your code looks like. Broadly speaking you can do `'amount' => 'between:'.request()->input('min').','.request()->input('max')` (you may need to adjust the fields) however it's probably best to validate the min and max fields before you do this otherwise they might not be valid

Comment: In your question you mentioned _configuration_ of _Products_. If it's the case, then I'd suspect that is either because you 1) have a static configuration of products (with, for example, `id`, `name`, `min_amount`, `max_amount`) or 2) a _Product_ Model, with a `products` table. If that's the case, you can modify your validator to fetch that config (or that _Product_ Model from DB) _prior_ of running the validation code and do: `'amount' => "between:{$specificProductMinAmount},{$specificProductMaxAmount}"`

Comment: I just updated my post

Answer (score 2):

In Livewire, you have two options to define rules of the component (three options in Livewire v3 with the new Attribute approach). However only one of them is dynamic, and this is what you'll need. Since you haven't provided any code, I'll assume that you have an `$productId` and a computed property for obtaining the product.

To achieve dynamic rules in Livewire, use the `rules()` method (and do not use the `protected $rules = []` attribute).

```php
class Product extends Component
{
    public $productId;
    public $amount;

    public function getProductProperty()
    {
        return Product::find($this->productId);
    }

    protected function rules() 
    {
        $product = $this->product;
        $rules = [
            'amount' => ['required'],
        ];

        if ($product->min_amount) {
            $rules['amount'][] = 'min:'.$product->min_amount;
        }
        if ($product->max_amount) {
            $rules['amount'][] = 'max:'.$product->max_amount;
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my post, is this automatically applies in laravel validation or is there something I need to do first?

Comment: For one, I'm assuming that you're using Livewire on top of Laravel. But you'll need to call `$this->validate();` and it'll use the rules defined in that method.

Comment: How do I call the rules withn the validate

Comment: If you're using Livewire, then you don't need to pass anything in when you define a `$rules` property, or like I showed, a `rules()` method. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation